# Replacing listBox items during repopulation

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm building a contact manager program and I have a button that when pressed, updates a listBox of names. Unfortunately, I'm expecting my user to not always be putting the names in before closing the program. I have decided to make new contacts in the list appear as random numbers before a name is entered, so some of my items will be numbers and some will be names. I can't seem to get the names to show up, though. I've been storing the names as strings inside of text files contained inside folders of unique random numbers. What I want is to be able to load all the folder names into the list, then check to see if a name is associated with the item, and if it is, replace the number with the respective name. The following code is as far as I have gotten before I got stumped.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //populate the list of people
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\PersonalManager\");
    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {
        //replace numbered items with names
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            String Text = Convert.ToString(listBox1.Items[i]);
            Text = Text.Replace(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\PersonalManager\"+listBox1.Items[i]+@"\first.txt")); //first.txt is the file containing the name
            listBox1.Items[i] = Text;
        }
        listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(dir));
    }
}
```

I'm also pretty sure there is an overload bug in there somewhere, as Visual Studio refuses to compile it. Maybe I should go about this in a different way? What would any of you suggest? I have searched all through Google, and Bing but have yet to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Sorry if my code is a mess, it's my first time.

P.S. I'm a beginner, so I can't wrap my head around too much code without comments every now and then.

Comment: You clear with `listBox1.Items.Clear();` and because of that there will be never a item in the list box..

Comment: I think he is clearing it so he doesn't have keep writing the same names to the listbox, he is adding them  here listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(dir)); @CSharper

Comment: the clearing is because this is a refresh function. I clear the list, then repopulate it.

Comment: Whats the content of the file?

Comment: the name of the contact is in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this line is breaking your code:

```
Text = Text.Replace(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\PersonalManager\"+listBox1.Items[i]+@"\first.txt"));
```

The `string.Replace` does not have a overload with just one parameter. It has always two.

Just to give you a starting point:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //populate the list of people
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\PersonalManager\");
    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {

       var filePathToRead = Path.Combine(dir, "first.txt");
       var allTextOfTheFile = File.ReadAllText(filePathToRead);

        // now you can work with the content of the file

        listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(dir));
    }
}
```